# De que manera logro condicionar los valores a ingresar en atributos?

Tags: python

Simplemente quiero que al ingresar el ID solo me acepté numeros enteros, al ingresar nombres solo acepte strings y al ingresar la lista de cursos solo acepte strings, y no cualquier tipo de datos.

```
class Estudiantes:
    id = int
    nombre = str
    lista_cursos = []


Estudiantes.id = input("Ingrese el ID del estudiante: ")

Estudiantes.nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")

Estudiantes.listas_cursos= input("Ingrese la lista de cursos: ")

print(Estudiantes.id)
print(Estudiantes.nombre)
print(Estudiantes.listas_cursos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Veo que hay varios errores de concepto así que te recomiendo repasar lo que son las [`clases`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html#:%7E:text=Las%20clases%20de%20Python%20proveen,clase%20base%20con%20el%20mismo) y como usarlas. La respuesta es extensa ya que hay varios puntos que corregir.

Un poco de contexto para entender mejor la respuesta que propongo:

Hay dos (Vamos a llamarlos) "niveles" para revisar el tipo de datos que el código utiliza. El "nivel superior", que sería la interfaz del usuario, es decir, lo que el usuario ingresa al programa, y el "nivel inferior", que sería a nivel de la clase, es decir, tu clase debe revisar si lo que está entrando y devolviendo tiene los tipos de datos correctos.

Hay ocaciones en que el nivel inferior es ignorado (En lo personal, siempre lo utilizo) si el único uso de la clase es a través de la interfaz del usuario, es decir, si las instancias de la clase reciben y devuelven datos que han sido ingresados directamente por el usuario y el nivel superior está bien implementado. Pero hay ocaciones en que las instancias de la clase son modificadas por código interno (Tal vez otras clases o funciones) y el nivel inferior te ayudaría a detectar errores a nivel de desarrollador.

Hay ocaciones en las que el nivel superior es ignorado si el nivel inferior está bien implementado, ya que proveerá información al usuario sobre el tipo de dato erróneo que está ingresando.

De la documentación oficial:

> Las clases proveen una forma de empaquetar datos y funcionalidad
> juntos. Al crear una nueva clase, se crea un nuevo tipo de objeto,
> permitiendo crear nuevas instancias de ese tipo. Cada instancia de
> clase puede tener atributos adjuntos para mantener su estado. Las
> instancias de clase también pueden tener métodos (definidos por su
> clase) para modificar su estado.

Esas instancias que se mencionan son las que se deben utilizar para trabajar con la clase, no de forma directa como lo muestras en tu pregunta, es decir, te hace falta crear una instancia:

```
estudiantes = Estudiantes()
```

Esta instancia puede utilizar todas los atributos y métodos (Funciones internas) de la clase, por lo que puedes acceder a ellos a través de la notación punto, es decir, `estudiantes.id`, `estudiantes.nombre` y `estudiantes.listas_cursos`

Las clases normalmente utilizan un método llamado `__init__` para inicializar las instancias

**Nota:** `id` es un nombre reservado en `Python` por lo que lo cambié a `identificador`, pero cuando se utiliza como atributo de la clase ya no causa problemas.

```
class Estudiantes:
    def __init__(self, identificador, nombre, lista_cursos):
        # Atributos de la clase
        self.id = identificador
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.lista_cursos = lista_cursos
```

Esto nos permite pasar información al crear una nueva instancia de la clase, de la siguiente forma:

```
# Las variables utilizadas en este ejemplo aún no existen, son para
# representar los argumentos que recibirá la instancia estudiantes
estudiantes = Estudiantes(identificador, nombre, lista_cursos)
```

Para implementar el nivel inferior podemos utilizar [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) de la siguiente forma:

```
class Estudiantes:
    def __init__(self, identificador, nombre, lista_cursos):
        if isinstance(identificador, int):
            self.id = identificador
        else:
            raise TypeError('El valor del número identificador debe ser int')
        
        if isinstance(nombre, str):
            self.nombre = nombre
        else:
            raise TypeError('El valor del nombre debe ser string')
        
        if all(isinstance(s, str) for s in lista_cursos):
            self.listas_cursos = lista_cursos
        else:
            raise TypeError('La lista debe contener únicamente string')
```

O podríamos utilizar las librerías `Typeguard` y `Typing` para hacerlo más compacto (Te recomiendo leer la documentación de ambas para entender como funcionan):

```
from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import List

@typechecked
class Estudiantes:
    # Después de cada argumento se pone el tipo de dato que recibe.
    # El decorador "typechecked" se encargará de revisar que únicamente
    # reciban el tipo de datos que ponemos después de los dos puntos ":"
    def __init__(self, identificador: int, nombre: str, lista_cursos: List[str]):
        self.id = identificador
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.lista_cursos = lista_cursos
```

Para tu ejercicio tal vez sería suficiente con implementar el nivel inferior, ya que en caso de que el usuario ingrese algún dato con tipo de variable diferente al esperado entonces recibirá un error, por ejemplo si ingreso un `string` en `identificador` se recibirá alguno de los siguientes errores:

```
# Utilizando el código con isinstance()
TypeError: El valor del número identificador debe ser int

# Utilizando el decorador typechecked
TypeError: type of argument "identificador" must be int; got str instead
```

El nivel superior podría implementarse con `try` y `except`, mostrándolo únicamente con `identificador` para no hacer la respuesta más larga, sería:

```
try:
    identificador = int(input("Ingrese el ID del estudiante: "))
except ValueError:
    print('El valor del número identificador ingresado por el usuario debe ser int')
```

**Nota:** `input()` siempre devuelve un `string` por lo que debes convertir la entrada a entero (`int`) para el número identificador.

Ejemplo completo del nivel inferior utilizando el decorador `typechecked`, si deseas implementar el nivel superior puedes utilizar `try` y `except` para cada valor ingresado por el usuario.

```
from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import List

@typechecked
class Estudiantes:
    def __init__(self, identificador: int, nombre: str, lista_cursos: List[str]):
        self.id = identificador
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.lista_cursos = lista_cursos

identificador = int(input("Ingrese el ID del estudiante: "))
nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")
lista_cursos= input("Ingrese la lista de cursos: ").split()

estudiantes = Estudiantes(identificador, nombre, lista_cursos)

print(estudiantes.id)
print(estudiantes.nombre)
print(estudiantes.lista_cursos)
```

Muestra del funcionamiento:

```
# Valore de entrada
Ingrese el ID del estudiante:  9
Ingrese el nombre del estudiante:  Juan
Ingrese la lista de cursos:  Curso1 Curso2 Curso3

# Valores de salida
9
Juan
['Curso1', 'Curso2', 'Curso3']
```

Answer (score 0):

La función `input()` siempre retorna un string; no es necesario hacer nada especial para ingresar nombres y otros datos textuales.

Para ingresar valores enteros o de punto flotante se usa el siguiente patrón:

```
while True:
    try:
        valor = int(input("Ingrese valor: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No es un valor entero!")
```

Este es un ciclo infinito. En cada iteración pides el valor y de inmediato lo transforma a entero con `int()`. Si no es un entero se producirá una excepción `ValueError`.

Si encerramos lo anterior en un `try-except` podemos capturar la excepción y mostrar un mensaje de error apropiado, luego de lo cual seguimos en el ciclo infinito y volveremos a pedir el valor.

Si el valor ingresado es válido, se ejecuta la siguiente instrucción (`break`), que rompe el ciclo.

#### Demo

```
while True:
    try:
        valor = int(input("Ingrese valor: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No es un valor entero!")

print(f"El valor ingresado es {valor}")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese valor: jjhk
No es un valor entero!
Ingrese valor: ioa
No es un valor entero!
Ingrese valor: 123
El valor ingresado es 123

Process finished with exit code 0
```